# Office365: Scripting One Drive for Business with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office-365, onedrive-for-business

In Office 365, a One Drive instance for a user is typically created when they click on their "About Me" page.

Does anyone know if it's possible to avoid this by having One Drive instances created for all users by a PowerShell Script?  I've not seen any PowerShell specific Cmdlets so any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In one of the most recent updates to the SharePoint Online Management shell, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588, they introduced a new commandlet called `Request-SPOPersonalSite`. You simply supply a list of no more than 200 users, and it will preprovision their OneDrives.

Comment: Good info :) Just out of curiosity, how do you keep track of this stuff?

Comment: Appreciate the quick answer.  I'll give it a go and will mark up for points

Comment: I'm always checking that, cause I hate writing CSOM in PowerShell, I'd rather have native components, so I'm constantly check to see if new commandlets are being created. It was possible before the update, but was a pain in the ass to do.